# Execute sql commands in Visual Studio server explorer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I execute SQL commands in Visual Studio Server Explorer?

When I right click a sql directory (like tables), I get the options:

- Add new table
- Compare data
- Execute query

But I want to do none of these, what I want is an empty screen where I can type my command, and execute it.

I don't want to use "Execute query" for writing commands, because it's for writing "queries", not all commands.

---

Alright, this is a pretty retarded solution to this problem but I guess it's good enough for me. I downloaded SQL Managment Studio, and installed it. It comes with a handy "Ssms.exe" that's hidden somewhere in program files with which you can manage your db.

Comment: What's wrong with "Execute query"?

Comment: An sql command is not necessarily a query.

Comment: You can type them there anyway, just hide the diagram and critera panes as they are not very useful in this case.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer my question. I don't "like" typing commands in a place that's made for writing queries. If I don't have a choice then that's that, but that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server point of view; a "command" and a query is the same thing. It is evaluated by the same code in the server.

A "command" is a SQL server DDL (Data Definition Language). A query is a SQL server DML (Data Manipulation Language). In a SQL server command batch use can issue both DDL and DML.

Answer (score 0):

The "New Query" button which will give you the behavior you are expecting is available by adding the menu through View > Toolbars > **Transact-SQL Editor**